# Eclipse cannot see java.time library on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

currently, I have a java project, at first I started my project on windows however now I had to switch ubuntu 14.04 (Dont worry, I dont have any OS dependent part on my project). Unfortunatelly, eclipse on ubuntu cannot see  libraries starting with `jave.time`. For example

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
```

in these lines it is written that  *The import java.time cannot be resolved* (Other libraries are succesfully detected)

As far as I saw on the web, I had to install JDK 8 for using time library I guess. However, I dont know how to do that in ubuntu [this is my first time for ubuntu]

Let me explain what I did so far, I installed JDK with the following commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

[By the way I wanted to install Oracle Java but  instead these commands installed Open JDK]

Now output of `java -version` command is :

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

When I look at the eclipse->help->installation details

```
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_75-b13
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.7
```

So, How could I solve my problem ? But as I said at the beginning of my question, this is my first time with ubuntu so while explaining could you also provide necessary commands?

Comment: This question is really "How do I install Java 8 on Ubuntu" rather than "How do I use java.time" - as such it *might* be more appropriate on askubuntu.com (indeed, http://askubuntu.com/questions/464755 seems relvevant). Have you checked what the `oracle-java8-installer` package actually installs? Perhaps (as suggested in the name) it only installs an installer, which you then need to run...

Comment: You may have to update Eclipse to point to the JDK 8, you may have to update your `PATH` variable, or both.

Comment: @JonSkeet I could not check it, if I had to run it after installing, do you know how could I do it ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had installed Eclipse after installing jdk but still do I have to ? And if so, how could I do it ?

Comment: @bulakbulaki: Not offhand - but as I mentioned, there other web pages explaining how to install Java on Ubuntu 14.04. As this isn't really a programming question, I don't think it's a great fit for SO. (I know it's sort of about programming tools, but it's more relevant on an Ubuntu-specific site, IMO.)

Comment: @JonSkeet so, should i delete my answer?

Comment: @kucing_terbang: Not sure, to be honest. We'll see if others close the question... (I'm on the fence, personally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [repository guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) try run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

After that, try to restart your eclipse.

The problem is, as described as Jon and Tim, is because your environment is still using the java version 7.

---

1. In your eclipse, open the preferences page

   [image: preferences]
2. then, go to the installed jre option under java tree

[image: second]

3. from there, click the add button, choose *Standard VM* and then add the installed java 8 jdk home folder and click finish.
4. check the check box and then try build your project again.

Comment: ,thanks for reply, as you said, I did and my environment is now using 1.8 however error still exist do you have any other idea?

Comment: It isn't wrong to update the environment, but Eclipse has its own `ini` file for determining which JDK to build and run with.

Comment: yeah, you're right but i thought `eclipse.ini` vm argument is only used to run eclipse.. never mind, i'll try to update the answer

Comment: @bulakbulaki then i guess you need to update the installed jdk option on the eclipse preferences. and then use it as your default compiler. on the side note, could you check where java is installed? usually, it should be around `usr/lib/jvm` folder

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have installed the Java 8 JDK (the correct version to use for `java.time`, q.v. Jon Skeet's answer), you still need to tell Eclipse to point to this JDK.

Open the `eclipse.ini` file and search for lines which look like the following:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

Then replace that path with the correct path to your JDK 8.  You will also need to restart your IDE.

As a quick check to see if Eclipse be using the JDK 8, you can `import java.time.*` at the top of one your classes and see whether you get errors.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen Do I have to it in eclipse or from command line ?

Comment: You can open the file anywhere.  There is also probably a way to do this from the GUI inside Eclipse.